# Inno Setup Avoiding exceptions in ExtractTemporaryFiles when no matching files are found

Tags: inno-setup

I have an issue with `ExtractTemporaryFiles` while extracting `*.sql` files

I don't always have SQL scripts inside `[Files]` section to extract as mentioned below. My problem is `ExtractTemporaryFiles('*.sql')` raises an exception if no sql files are included with the installation.

> Internal error: ExtractTemporaryFiles: No files matching "*.sql" found.

I can use `try:except` or another ugly way like, including a `dummy.sql` with the installation always. So I can make sure `ExtractTemporaryFiles` has a file to extract it always.

But I want to know What is the best way of avoiding exception in this case?

```
[Files]
Source: "Input\SQLSCRIPTS\*"; DestDir: "SQLSCRIPTS"; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to conditionally skip the `ExtractTemporaryFiles` call:

```
#if FindFirst("Input\SQLSCRIPTS\*.sql", 0)
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('*.sql');
#endif
```